# Rabbi Avraham Ben Harambam Commentary on the Torah

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Maimonides), Rabbi Avraham Ben Harambam wrote a commentary on the Torah. Is there anywhere I can find a copy of this online?

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/R-AVRAHAM-BEN-HARAMBAM-Commentary-on-the-Torah-/372870295843 https://www.ebay.com/itm/R-AVRAHAM-BEN-HARAMBAM-Commentary-on-Shemot/393142142650

Comment: It's been digitized and put on Alhatorah (feel free to convert to answer)

Comment: @רבותמחשבות thanks!

Comment: IINM these are all translations from judeo arabic so the newest edition I linked above is probably your best bet if you're very serious about this

Comment: @DoubleAA Good to know Shemos came out. Last I had checked they only had Bereishis.

Comment: @Alex It's very new https://seforimblog.com/2021/03/new-sefer-announcement-%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%a9-%d7%94%d7%aa%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%94-%d7%9c%d7%a8%d7%91%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%95-%d7%90%d7%91%d7%a8%d7%94%d7%9d-%d7%91%d7%9f-%d7%94%d7%a8%d7%9e%d7%91%d7%9d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access his peirush on Bereishis and Shemos on the Otzar website [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=159027&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16179918851131122)

Comment: Can someone please explain why this answer received a downvote.

Comment: likely because it is behind a paywall...

Comment: Thanks @רבותמחשבות - however, you can still access a good 150 pages without paying?

Comment: The intro takes up much of that section. You basically posted a link to Bereishit through Vayeitzei, which while somewhat useful, pales in comparison to another answer which found the sefer in its entirety for free online. My assumption when reading the question (although it may be unfounded) was that the individual was looking for a free copy online of the full commentary.

Answer (score 6):

R. Solomon David Sassoon (1915–1985) published Rabbenu Abraham's commentary on Genesis/Exodus (the only sections largely extant) from a Bodleian manuscript in 1965. It is available to download for free at HebrewBooks:

[**פירוש רבינו אברהם בן הרמב"ם על התורה**](https://hebrewbooks.org/40223)